# ActionController::RoutingError when test custom devise controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm trying to add a custom action to Devise's registration controller which allows users to change their passwords (I cannot use default `registrations#edit` since I need a form for changing only password, not email/username). The implementation I wrote below works in development mode but I get this error when I test controller.

```
Failure/Error: get 'password'
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches {:controller=>"registrations", :action=>"password"}
```

There is my code (I tried to skip unrelated parts)

`spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb`

```
describe RegistrationsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before :each do
    request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:users]
  end

  describe "GET 'password'" do
    it "..." do
                     # The problem is here,
      get 'password' # it raises ActionController::RoutingError
    end
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
  def password
  end
end
```

---

`config/routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, path: 'account', 
  controllers: { registrations: 'registartions' }, 
  skip: [:registartions, :sessions]

devise_scope :user do
  # ...
  scope '/account' do
    get 'password' => 'devise/registartions#password', as: "change_password
  do
end
```

`spec_helper.rb`

```
# ...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would usually add a comment for this, but I'm including a code block and it gets messy in comments.

It seems like you're trying to preform a `GET` on `/password` instead of on `/account/password`.

From what I'm reading, you've got a mapping for `/account/password`:

```
devise_scope :user do # used to remove /users/ part from devise URLs
  # ...
  scope '/account' do # adds /account to URLs
    get 'password' => 'devise/registartions#password', as: "change_password"  
    # this will match /account/passwordAnswer

  do
end
```

So you should either remove the scope, or replace your get request in test with this:

```
get "/account/password", :user => @user
```

or this

```
get change_password_path(@user)
```

Where `@user` is a `User`'s mock.

Run `rake routes` to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up your config/routes.rb with the following.

```
devise_for :users do
    get 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get 'changepassword' => 'devise/registrations#edit'
    get 'access' => 'homepages#access'
    get 'history' => 'policies#history'
    get 'future' => 'policies#future'
  end
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => :sessions }
  resources :users
```

I have the same problem. I set the routes then it was worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using `get "/account/password"` or a path in my spec. Seems hacky. I fixed a similar problem by using better syntax in my routes.rb file:

1. Using `path: 'account'` option in `devise_for`
2. Explicitly setting my custom controller with `controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}`

So my routes.rb looks like this:

```
devise_for  :users, 
            path: 'account', 
            path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', sign_up: 'register'},                 
            controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'},
            skip: [:passwords]
```

Then I can use `get :new` in my test. Much cleaner.

Hope this helps someone else.

I am using devise 3.0.